# Id property of my model not POSTed back

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I've tried using:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CategoryId)
```

and

```
 <input type="hidden" name="@Model.CategoryId"
        id="CategoryId" value="@Model.CategoryId" />
```

but none seem to post back the CategoryId and bind it, and all I receive is the default 0, making me unable to Edit my Model

Using FormCollection in the post method, I do get the value, but I want the default model binder to do it.

Here's my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
  if (id == null)
  {
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  Category category = db.Categories.Find(id);
  if (category == null)
  {
    return HttpNotFound();
  }
  return View(category);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CategoryId, Name")] Category category)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  return View(category);
}
```

Here's my View:

```
@model Category 
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <input type="hidden" name="CategoryId" value=@Model.CategoryId id="CategoryId"/>

        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div>
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**EDIT**
Here's my Model:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CategoryValidation))]
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Features = new List<Feature>();
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

**2nd EDIT**
I can simply use either of FormCollection in the HttpPost Action or "(int? id)" to bind the posted model's Id manually, before modifying the Database's state, but why doesn't ModelBinder do it when posting the model back?

Comment: Have you tried using an `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CategoryId")` instead of hard coding it?

Comment: Are the other properties of your model object gets their values bound properly?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid yes, as I stated, I've tried that, but "Id" wont bound

Comment: @ngergo6 yes, other properties of the model get bound properly except the Id

Comment: @Mehrdadmaskull :  id is not binded in which action? HTTPPOST? or the one with parameter int? id?

Comment: @Mehrdadmaskull : have you checked the edit with parameter(int? id) ? is it present there?

Comment: @Shiv in the HttpPost action, and well I can simply use the FormCollection or (int? id) to change the posted model's Id before adding it to the Database, but why doesn't it bind it automatically??

Comment: @Mehrdadmaskull : there is no problem in the [HTTPPOST] however I suspect that it might not coming from public ActionResult Edit(int? id) action. can you check if it is present by inspectiong your page or adding breakpoint on return View?

Comment: @Shiv I checked by using the breakpoint, and the correct Id is sent to the View...however I guess the problem is within the HiddenFor Html Helper method that gets overridden somewhere I don't know!!

Comment: @Mehrdadmaskull: It can only happen if you have more then one element on the view with the same id. please open the page source (ctrl + U) and find CategoryId.

Comment: @Shiv looks like the problem wasn't the ModelBinder or the View or the Controller, I finally found it and it's the Model which it's getting it's data annotations from...if you're interested to know why, check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the other class my Model was retrieving it's Data Annotations from

```
[Bind(Exclude = "CategoryId")]
public class CategoryValidation
{
    [Display(Name = "Category's Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(CategoryValidation))]
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        Features = new List<Feature>();
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }

    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; } 
}
```

Removing the Attribute [Bind(Exclude = "CategoryId")] allowed the ModelBinder to properly bind the Id

This works with both using the Razor Syntax HiddenFor Html Helper method and the input type-hidden tag